# Class of all finite sets closed under difference and product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can't really see this - but is the class of all finite sets closed under Set difference and product?

Set difference: $A \setminus B := \{a \mid a\in A \text{ and } a\notin B\}$.

Set product: $(A \times B) := \{(a,b) \mid a\in A \text{ and } b\in B\}$.

Comment: Yes. Just count or estimate th enumber of elements in those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, suppose $A,B$ are finite sets having cardinality $|A|,|B| \in \mathbb{N}$, then your question is are $A \setminus B$ and $A\times B$ also finite?

Try to work out, in terms of $|A|,|B|$, the maximum possible cardinality of $A \setminus B$ and $A\times B$. You should then be able to answer your question.